# Adding some more fields to the form in yii2 using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I have a `Yii2 form`:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'que']); ?>
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'type')
            ->dropDownList($questionTypes, [
                'class' => 'form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched',
                'prompt' => 'Select question type',
                'ng-model' => 'que.type',
                'ng-change' => 'addAnswerOptions(que);',
        ]);
    ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

On the basis of selected dropdown value, I have to add some more fields to the same form of the same model. What fields will be added, is totally depend on the dropdown value.

How can I do this?

Comment: I can definitely help with this but would need a bit more information. Do you know in advance which fields you want to display on each scenario? Or is this a case where the user could add extra fields by clicking a button (thus meaning we don't know exactly how many fields there will be in each case)

Comment: Yeah I know the fields that need to be added in advance for each scenario. Its like if `type==1` I have to add 2 fields (which are also the part of model) named as `option1`, `option2`, for `type==2` I have to add 4 more fields `option1,option2,option3,option4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the information you give out here is what I would suggest.

**1) Dynamic - no AJAX**

Build your form with all the fields you need, just contain each "scenario" in a separate `div` like follows:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'que']); ?>
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'type')
            ->dropDownList($questionTypes, [
                'class' => 'form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched',
                'prompt' => 'Select question type',
                'ng-model' => 'que.type',
                'ng-change' => 'addAnswerOptions(que);',
        ]);
    ?>
    <div class="form-option" data-type="class" style="display:none;">
        <?php
            // ... fields here for case type == class
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-option" data-type="prompt" style="display:none;">
        <?php
            // ... fields here for case type == prompt
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-option" data-type="ng-model" style="display:none;">
        <?php
            // ... fields here for case type == ng-model
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-option" data-type="ng-change" style="display:none;">
        <?php
            // ... fields here for case type == ng-change
        ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Then you will want to register Javascript code to display the correct blocs depending on which dropdown option was selected.
Bellow is an example using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.form-control').change(function(){
        $('.form-option').hide(); // hide all options if an option is showing
        var index = $('select.form-control').index();
        $('div[data-type="'+index+'"]').show(); //show the correct fields
    });
});
```

If you're going to go this way I suggest you use [AJAX validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ajax-validation) for your form. It will avoid you having to deal with a headache on page reload.

Once your form is submitted you will have to handle each case in your controller. You can either use a simple set of `if()` statements that check the drop down value. Or you can set your model [validation scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios) according to the drop down value.

The advantage of this is that it will be quicker and you will be able to take advantage of `ActiveForm`. the cons are that you need to know which fields you want to display for each option, and it doesn't allow you to cumulate `n` number of fields when you don't know how much `n` is.

**2) Using Ajax**

In the event that you want to use ajax calls to load the extra form fields you will have to make a `controller/action` combination that will return the fields depending on the type that you pass in the `GET`

This action will generate the html of the fields you want to display. Here's an example:

```
public function actionAjaxFields($type)
{
    $html = '';
    if($type == "class")
    {
        $html .= Html::textInput('Field1');
    }
    elseif($type == "prompt")
    {
        $html .= Html::textInput('Field2');
    }
    else
    {
        // etc...
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Note that you can also pass a user id to this method which will allow you to generate a model and use `Html::activeTextInput()`, however you will not be able to take advantage of `ActiveForm` features.

Once this is done, you should bind a function to the change event of the dropdown and use something along the lines of :

```
var responsePromise = $http.get("controller/ajax-fields", {params: {type: <type-from-dropdown>}});
```

Unfortunately I do not know much about angularjs so this is the extent of the help I can give on the javascript side of things. I'm sure there's more than enough information on google/stackoverflow about binding events and appending data to the DOM in angularjs to get you running.

Let me know if I can be of any extra help on the Yii2 side.

Comment: I don't want it do it with `jquery`, I want to load them at real time using ajax.

Comment: Ok so you want to load this in real time. But are you using a JavaScript library like jquery for your Ajax calls or not at all? Also, if using Ajax you will not be able to take advantage of $form. You should be made aware of this.

Comment: actually, I am using `angularjs`  to make an `ajax` request and load fields.

Comment: then you could add an angularjs tag to the question

Comment: I updated my answer with some information concerning ajax calls and how to proceed on the Yii2 end. Unfortunately I'm not well versed in angularjs (hence the tag comment by @deacs ) so I can't be of incredible help on that end. Let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: In your answer you updated, As I am looking to do it using ajax so coming to that part only, I have a line in my question `have to add some more fields to the same form of same model. `, its because I want to retain all the client validations that comes up with a form model. but by just rendering fields using `Html` class I will loose that benefit of `Yii form` and I don't want that. I hope I am making my point clear

Comment: You can use `Html::activeTextInput()` instead as I mentioned in the answer for this. You will have to pass the `model::id` to the `GET` request in order to generate the proper model in the controller. Then you can use `activeTextInput($model, 'attribute)`. This will allow for you to take advantage of model validation. Using ajax however you will not be able to take advantage of `ActiveForm` features so you will have to manually set up the labels and error fields for example (`Html::activeLabel()` and `Html::error()`)

Comment: Thank you @D.Mill for all your valuable input in answer to question